# using $Call<F> to extract argument type in flow

Tags: flowtype

Consider this code:

```
type Func = number => number

type X = $Call<<A, R>(A => R) => R, Func>
type Y = $Call<<A, R>(A => R) => A, Func>
```

Using `flow 0.77`, `X` is the type `number`: flow has successfully extracted the **R**eturned type in `Func`. But `Y` is `empty`, where I would expect `number`, ie the type of the first **A**rgument in `Func`.

Why is `Y` `empty` instead of `number`?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/854 and https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4672